# Is it possible to reference the 'current' value of a SUM() within the SUM() function of a MySQL select statement

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm trying to sum all the values for a field up to a designated 'max_value'.  Once the SUM() function hits the 'max_value', no more values will be added to the sum.

SUM(CASE WHEN (**this_expr** <= max_value) THEN *table.field* ELSE 0 END) AS **this_expr**, ...

Is this possible?  What should **this_expr** be?  What should the proper syntax look like.

I realize that from this example it would be easier to perform a "CASE WHEN (SUM(*table.field*) > max_value) THEN max_value ELSE SUM(*table.field*) END" however the main goal is to be able to reference the **this_expr** field/variable within other CASE functions within the select.  Kinda like capturing the exact instance in which the **this_expr** has reached the max_value

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: it sounds like you want to use a stored procedure with a cursor.  see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: Yes, sure it is. in the first and quick look you can do a sub select with your case statment then do a select to this subselect with the sum statement. The trick will be on the subselect case. There you will have to make your expression to: till reach the max bring value else bring 0 and the sum will do the rest. I'm getting out now, if I came back and no one answer you, I will.

Comment: Can you show sample data, and how you would expect to sum the values with the final results?